# Would the TFS allow more than 5 users to use if registered?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a tfs 2015 installed on our server.

I read that only 5 users can use the TFS if trial version. So we registered the tfs using license key. Now it's activated.

So still I have the 5 users limitation or it has been removed?

Comment: The two ways to acquire TFS CALs are:

   1) Purchase a TFS User CAL   (sku: 126-00196)

   2) 1 TFS CAL (and 1 TFS Server license) is included in each Visual Studio/MSDN subscription. Thus, anyone who has an active MSDN subscription assigned to them is covered with a TFS CAL.    https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/govdev/2012/05/14/understand-tfs-licensing/

Answer (score 0):

> To license TFS server      , you’ll need a **TFS server license** and a
>   Windows operating system license (Windows Server is best) for each
>   machine running TFS, plus **a client access license for each person
>   connecting to TFS**. Client access licenses (CALs) aren’t required for
>   people who just access work items – assign them “Stakeholder” access,
>   which is free.
>
> Extensions to TFS such as **Test Manager**, Package Management, and
>   Private Pipelines require an additional purchase. Some TFS Extensions
>   are included with **Visual Studio Enterprise subscriptions** and many
>   others are free. Paid extensions can also be purchased monthly, no
>   Visual Studio subscription is required.

In your case, you do not have the 5 users limitation, but if you want to use some TFS features such as Build/ Check in out after 5 free quotas used, you will need to purchase them.

Unlike the Classic Purchasing above, if you don't want to buy a MSDN subscription.
Suggest you to use Modern Purchasing.

> The most advantage: No need to make a 3-year purchasing commitment for
>   TFS—you can pay month-to-month and cancel any time. For example: Buy
>   VSTS for TFS CALs. When you buy VSTS users (starting at $6/month),
>   those same users have a TFS CAL and can connect to any TFS in your
>   organization. If those users also need TFS extensions like Test
>   Manager or Package Management, or if you need additional Private
>   Pipelines for your team, you can purchase these through the Visual
>   Studio Marketplace. All VSTS charges are month-to-month. See detailed
>   [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-access-tfs-test-hub?view=tfs-2018).

For more info you could take a look at this official doc: [**Team Foundation Server Pricing**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/server/)

---

Besides, If you want to double confirm this and  know more information about TFS license, you could call 1-800-426-9400, Monday through Friday, 6:00 A.M. to 6:00 P.M. (Pacific Time) to speak directly to a Microsoft licensing specialist, and you can get more detail information from there. Worldwide customers can use the Guide to Worldwide Microsoft Licensing Sites to find contact information in their locations: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/